# How can I aggregate groups in data.table and exclude the row itself?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table `vb` that looks like this:

```r
library(data.table)
vb <- data.table(cluster = c(1,1,2), name = c(34, 82, 10))
#>    cluster name 
#> 1:       1   34                      
#> 2:       1   82                      
#> 3:       2   10
```

I would like to create a new column `other names in same cluster` which is the concatenation of the values of `name` by `cluster`. So the new data should look like this:

```r
#>    cluster name other_names_in_same_cluster
#> 1:       1   34                          82
#> 2:       1   82                          34
#> 3:       2   10                          NA
```

The following gives all names in the same cluster. How can I exclude the value in the column `name` from the row itself in `other_names_in_same_cluster`?

```r
vb[, "other_names_in_same_cluster" := paste(sort(unique(name)), collapse=", "), by = c("cluster")][]
#>    cluster name other_names_in_same_cluster
#> 1:       1   34                      34, 82
#> 2:       1   82                      34, 82
#> 3:       2   10                          10
```

What is the easiest way of doing this in data.table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vb[, onic := sapply(name, function(n) toString(setdiff(name, n))), cluster]
vb
#    cluster name onic
# 1:       1   34   82
# 2:       1   82   34
# 3:       2   10
```

With bigger data:

```r
vb <- data.table(cluster = c(1,1,2,1), name = c(34, 82, 10, 17))
vb[, onic := sapply(name, function(n) toString(setdiff(name, n))), cluster]
vb
#    cluster name   onic
# 1:       1   34 82, 17
# 2:       1   82 34, 17
# 3:       2   10       
# 4:       1   17 34, 82
```

Comment: I would recommend keeping the data as a list column instead of string: `vb[, onic := .(lapply(name, function(n) setdiff(name, n))), cluster]`